# Duda con el tratamiento de un esquema manyTomany y oneTomany mezclados

Tags: java, jsp, hibernate, maven, h2

Estoy haciendo un proyecto web de gestión de eventos para clase con [java](/questions/tagged/java), [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp), [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate), [h2](/questions/tagged/h2) y [maven](/questions/tagged/maven).

¿Cómo hago para asociar a los usuarios con los eventos y ambos con la tabla asiste?

Quiero que la aplicación recuerde qué usuario se ha inscrito a qué evento y su respectivo pago asociado, contando con que un usuario además de crear un evento puede también asistir a el, también hay un atributo `boolean` administrador para que sea el único usuario que pueda borrar a otros usuarios o añadirlos.

[image: Esquema BD]
[image: Estructura del proyecto]

> Pojo Asiste:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "asistentes")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.usuario", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idUsuario")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.evento", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idEvento")) })
public class Asiste {

// clave primaria-id compuesta

private UsuarioEventoId primaryKey = new UsuarioEventoId();

// campos adicionales
@Column(name = "nombreEntidad")
private String nombreEntidad;

@Column(name = "nombreCuenta")
private String nombreCuenta;

@Column(name = "iban")
private String iban;

@Column(name = "numeroCuenta")
private String numeroCuenta;

@Column(name = "fechaPago")
//@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Type(type="date")
private Date fechaPago;
```

> Pojo Evento:

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "eventos")
public class Evento {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "idEvento")
private long idEvento;

@Column(name = "nombreEvento")
private String nombreEvento;

@Column(name = "tipoEvento")
private String tipoEvento;

@Column(name = "descripcionEvento")
private String descripcionEvento;

@Column(name = "precioEvento")
private double precioEvento;

@Column(name = "fechaCreacion")
private Date fechaCreacion;

@Column(name = "fechaCelebracion")
@Type(type="date")
private Date fechaCelebracion;

// Los días que faltan para que se cumpla el evento
@Column(name = "diasRestantes")
private long diasRestantes;

@Column(name = "iva")
private double iva;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id")
private Usuario usuario;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryKey.evento",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
@ElementCollection(targetClass=Integer.class)
private Collection<Asiste> listadoAsistentes;
```

> Pojo Usuario:

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "usuarios")
public class Usuario {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "idUsuario")
private long idUsuario;

@Column(name = "nombreUsuario")
private String nombreUsuario;

@Column(name = "apellidosUsuario")
private String apellidosUsuario;

@Column(name = "contrasenia")
private String contrasenia;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "administrador")
private boolean administrador;

@Column(name = "preguntaSecreta")
private String preguntaSecreta;

@Column(name = "respuestaSecreta")
private String respuestaSecreta;

// ¿Sería lo adecuado?
@Column(name = "sexo")
private String sexo;

// Primera relación 1 a * con la tabla Evento
@OneToMany(mappedBy="usuario",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@ElementCollection(targetClass=Integer.class)
private Collection<Evento> listadoEventos;

// Relación de 1 a * con la tabla Asiste
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryKey.usuario",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
@ElementCollection(targetClass=Integer.class)
private Collection<Asiste> listadoAsistentes;
```

> Pojo UsuarioEventoId (embeddable class)

```
@Embeddable
public class UsuarioEventoId implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private Usuario usuario;


    private Evento evento;

    // Getters y Setters
    @ManyToOne
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }
    @ManyToOne
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    public Evento getEvento() {
        return evento;
    }

    public void setEvento(Evento evento) {
        this.evento = evento;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UsuarioEventoId [usuario=" + usuario + ", evento=" + evento + "]";
    }
```

> Servlet form Usuario

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String nombreUsuario = request.getParameter("nombreUsuario");
        String apellidosUsuario = request.getParameter("apellidosUsuario");
        String contrasenia = request.getParameter("contrasenia");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String preguntaSecreta = request.getParameter("preguntaSecreta");
        String respuestaSecreta = request.getParameter("respuestaSecreta");
        String sexo = request.getParameter("sexo");

        GestionUsuarios gestionUsuarios = new GestionUsuarios();

        // No tengo muy claro si con los campos a null funcionará correctamente
        // cuando se agreguen los objetos a la lista
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario(nombreUsuario, apellidosUsuario, contrasenia, email, false, preguntaSecreta,
                respuestaSecreta, sexo, null, null);

        gestionUsuarios.addUsuario(usuario);

        request.setAttribute("usuarios", gestionUsuarios.list());

        //response.sendRedirect("app/tablaUsuarios.jsp");

        //response.sendRedirect("app/tablaUsuarios.jsp");
        //Había que tener aquí un dispather para que la tabla se mostrara
        request.getRequestDispatcher("tablaUsuarios.jsp").forward(request, response);


    }
```

> Event form Servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse    response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // doGet(request, response);

    String nombreEvento = request.getParameter("nombreEvento");
    String tipoEvento = request.getParameter("tipoEvento");
    String descripcionEvento = request.getParameter("descripcionEvento");
    // Hacer el parseDouble
    String precioEvento = request.getParameter("precioEvento");

    double precioParseado = 0;
    try {
        precioParseado = Double.parseDouble(precioEvento);
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {

    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

    }

    // Fecha de creación: debe aparecer automáticamente
    Date fechaCreacion = new Date();

    // Fecha de celebración
    String fechaCeleb = request.getParameter("fechaCelebracion");

    DateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date fechaCelebracion = null;
    try {
        fechaCelebracion = formatoFecha.parse(fechaCeleb);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // De momento los días restantes estarán a null hasta que me de tiempo a
    // implementarlo(resta de fechas)
    String iva = request.getParameter("iva");

    double ivaParseado = 0;
    try {
        ivaParseado = Double.parseDouble(iva);
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {

    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

    }

    GestionEventos gestionEventos = new GestionEventos();



    Evento evento = new Evento(nombreEvento, tipoEvento, descripcionEvento, precioParseado, fechaCreacion,
            fechaCelebracion, 0, ivaParseado, null, null);


    gestionEventos.addEvento(evento);

    request.setAttribute("eventos", gestionEventos.list());

    request.getRequestDispatcher("tabla.jsp").forward(request, response);

}
```

> and Asiste form Servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    String nombreEntidad = request.getParameter("nombreEntidad");
    String nombreCuenta = request.getParameter("nombreCuenta");
    String iban = request.getParameter("iban");
    String numeroCuenta = request.getParameter("numeroCuenta");
    Date fechaPago = new Date();


    GestionAsistentes gestionAsistentes = new GestionAsistentes();

    // No tengo muy claro si con los campos a null funcionará correctamente
    // cuando se agreguen los objetos a la lista
    Asiste asistente = new Asiste(nombreEntidad, nombreCuenta, iban, numeroCuenta, fechaPago);

    gestionAsistentes.addAsistente(asistente);

    request.setAttribute("asistentes", gestionAsistentes.list());

    //response.sendRedirect("app/tablaUsuarios.jsp");

    //response.sendRedirect("app/tablaUsuarios.jsp");
    //Había que tener aquí un dispather para que la tabla se mostrara
    request.getRequestDispatcher("tablaAsiste.jsp").forward(request, response);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el mapeo de las entidades está incorrecto.

Concretamente en el mapeo de los asistentes dentro del pojo `Evento.java` haces uso de `@ElementCollection` este tipo de mapeo se emplea únicamente cuando el tipo de elemento referenciado es una entidad débil que depende de la primaria para existir (no tiene identidad propia), lo que viene a ser, tipos básicos o embebidos (`embedabbles`) en el [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html) de la anotación.

Este tipo de mapeos surgió con JPA 2 para facilitar relaciones de 1 a varios donde el elemento referenciado nunca va a tener identidad propia y solo tiene razón de ser asociado a una entidad fuerte. Por ejemplo teléfonos de un usuario.

Hay que tener en cuenta que los elementos referenciados al ser embebidos (con `@Embbedable`) no pueden ser entidades (con `@entity`) por lo que no se pueden persistir separadamente de la entidad fuerte a que van ligados, ni ser recuperados de la base de datos independientemente.

En tu caso, quitando los `@ElementCollection` la entidad evento quedaría:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "eventos") 
public class Evento {

    ...otros campos...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "primaryKey.evento",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Asiste> listadoAsistentes;
}
```

**Nota:** *No es muy recomendable hacer un `fetch EAGER` de colecciones completas por que puedes llegar a traer mas datos de base de datos de los que planeabas.*

La entidad usuario quedaría:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios") 
public class Usuario {

    ...otros campos...

    // Primera relación 1 a * con la tabla Evento
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="usuario",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Evento> listadoEventos;

    // Relación de 1 a * con la tabla Asiste
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "primaryKey.usuario",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Asiste> listadoAsistentes;

}
```